# LinearLayout inside another LinearLayout issue

Tags: android

i have a `LinearLayout` inside another `LinearLayout`. the issue i have is that the `ToggleButton` is not visible in the second `LinearLayout`..here is my complete UI.also i want to know is this layout design efficient or no. i know i can use `TableLayout` but then i have problem in fitting 3 components on one line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/supplierNameTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/supplierNameTV"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_gravity="right"/>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/supplierName_CB"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/prodNameTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/prodNameTV"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/prodName_CB"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/addproduct_button"
    android:textColor="#372c24" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to assign a layout_weight to your AutoCompleteTextView:

```
    <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/supplierName_CB"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

Comment: i added the code as you mentioned,but then the 2 wigets are not aligned staight.the button is little below the AutoComplete widget

Comment: `
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="ToggleButton" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/supplierName_CB"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>`

Comment: You should add `android:gravity="center_vertical"` to the LinearLayout containing the AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: now when i am testing on the device the AutoComplete is not responding,in the sense i cannot enter any text in the widget when i enable the toggle button.but when i use my old layout design it is working fine.what could it be

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pda.kaizen/com.pda.kaizen.activity.OrderActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ToggleButton
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ToggleButton
at com.pda.kaizen.activity.OrderActivity.onCreate
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

Comment: `supplierTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.supplierName_CB);`

Comment: Did you try to clean your project and rebuild it ? (sometimes eclipse gets a bit confused with IDs when changing layout files...)

Comment: yes i cleaned my project and rebuilt it but no luck,then i deleted the R.java and this time it worked!!.thanks

Answer (score 1):

With LinearLayout, you can easily assign layout weight. The root layout will have the weightsum of 100 and then the rest of layout will have their on weight. Though in this situation I recommend to use relative layout. The reason being performance as well as ease of support for different screens as the layout is relative.

For example in my case,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mst"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="98" >
</ListView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/btn_delete" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnExport"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/btn_export" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSelectAll"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/btn_select_all" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the AutoCompleteTextView took the whole width. Change it to:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Or use a fixed size (like 60dp).